# Challenge problems for new programmers

Tags: php, php-5.3

So I'm training someone at job in PHP, MySQL, HTML, etc and was wondering if anyone out there knew of any good entry-level challenges to have him complete in PHP.  I've had him do a bunch already and I'm starting to run out of ideas.  He has no previous programming experience.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/96504/how-can-i-teach-a-bright-person-with-no-programming-experience-how-to-program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate Age - accounts for pre 1970 dates, leap years, if birthday has passed in current year, birthday is in future, format of date.

Build on the classes he's created and extend them to do other things.

Output the contents of a multi-dimensional array - recursion.

Open a text file and extract data - memory management, max time execution.

Get mismatched records from two tables. LEFT JOIN ... x IS NULL

build a grid of data from a query - colspan when cells left over

recurring Ajax requests. Check database to see if X has been saved/updated. (2 user tick tack toe or chat room)

Comment: The calculate age problem is right up his alley, super simple concept, not so simple in code but not so complex that he'll spend an hour staring at php.net (which happens more than I like).

Answer (score 2):

How about a Guestbook? Image-Gallery? Small CMS? Simple Shop? a Blog?

Comment: I plan on having him do stuff like that, in the future.  Those are still a little advanced for him.  I'm looking for REALLY simple projects to demonstrate different parts of PHP and OOP.  For instance, one of the first things I had him do was take 2 numbers (total and tendered), calculate how much change would be given and then show that in appropriate bills and coins.  That took him about 3 times longer than I had expected.

Comment: Okey. Another idea would be a simple calculator. Very simple maths, great to start!

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go for a ecommerce site. They are pretty hard to make well so it would be a real challenge.

Make it with all the works, fully ordering and all cornjobs etc required to hold prices and special offers etc.

For real simple:

- Make a cronjob
- Learn how to call system commands from PHP
- Learn about the CLI

Comment: "He has no previous programming experience"  A fully operable e-commerce website is so far over his head right now that I think he'd just drown in it if I asked him to do that.

Comment: @AndrewBurgess I thought you said you had already sent him a number of challenges? He will struggle but with help he'll pull through.

Comment: Yes, I've given him a few tasks to complete, but it's all REALLY basic.  Such as taking 2 numbers as input and returning the change and how many bills/coins of each type should be given back.  That problem took him way longer than I had hoped.  I've also had him create a string, print it, reverse it, print again, swap words, print, reverse and print.  That also took him about 20 minutes.  That's WAY too long in my opinion, even without a knowledge of programming.  It's evident that he's not in the proper mindset yet, so I'm trying to help get him there.

Comment: @AndrewBurgess Since I am still quite young (barely out of uni) I know what it is like to learn languages and sometimes find it difficult to do things fast, even now I still program quite slowly in comparison to other people but I make less mistakes which means in the long run I actually program faster. Maybe he understands the language it is just that he is a slower programmer? If not then throwing him in the deep end with a set deadline used to help me in Uni.

Comment: I don't know, I'm fairly certain he's just not getting in the mindset. For instance, he regularly forgets quotes or semi-colons.  Or he forgets what he's named a variable, or even to declare one.  It's small things like that that show that he's not grasping the concept of programming.  I want to try to re-enforce this so it becomes more ingrained in his though process.